# How to compute $\dim_{\mathbb C}\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(z^4,x^2+y^2+z^2-1,xy)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> How to compute $\dim_{\mathbb C}\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(z^4,x^2+y^2+z^2-1,xy)$?

I tried to decompose $$(z^4,x^2+y^2+z^2-1,xy)=(z^4,x^2+y^2+z^2-1,x)\cap(z^4,x^2+y^2+z^2-1,y)=(z^4,x^2+z^2-1,y)\cap(z^4,y^2+z^2-1,x)$$ so I obtained a direct sum of two vector spaces. But I do not know how to continue to understand better the structure of that quotient.
Thank you!

Comment: Since you don't say what you're trying to do I'm not sure that it's relevant, but have you paid attention to the ideal $(z^4, x^2 + z^2 - 1, y) + (z^4, y^2 + z - 1, x)$?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is to have a more precise characterization of that ring. In particular i am interested in computing the dimensioni of that vector space over C.

Comment: Some context would help too. e.g. did this arise as an exercise in the theory of Groebner bases? Is using said theory even permissible?

Comment: The two ideals from the intersection are comaximal, so you can use the CRT.

Comment: Yes, i Can use Gbasis but i don't know if computation could be helpful. @user26857 I Can use CRT even if they were not comaximal because I have their intersection, not their product (or i am wrong?)

Comment: No. Co-maximality is essential for the CRT.

Comment: You're right, sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the CRT, the quotient is isomorphic to

$$\mathbb C[x,y,z]/(z^4,x^2+z^2-1,y) \times \mathbb C[x,y,z]/(z^4,y^2+z^2-1,x).$$

The two factors are isomorphic, hence it suffices to compute the dimension of one factor, i.e. compute the dimension of $\mathbb C[x,z]/(z^4,x^2+z^2-1).$

It is easy to choose some monomial order (i.e. such that $Z^4 > X^2 > Z^2$ holds), such that those two generators form a Groebner basis, hence the initial ideal is $(z^4,x^2)$ and $\dim \mathbb C[x,z]/(z^4,x^2)=8.$

Hence the dimension of your algebra is $16$.

Comment: why do you pass from $(z^4,x^2+z^2-1)$ to $(z^4,x^2)$?

Comment: When computing the dimension of the quotient, you can pass to the initial ideal.

Comment: By "initial ideal" of $I$ do you mean $Lt(I)$?

Comment: yes, exactly this.

Comment: A proof of the fact that i can consider only that monomial ideal?